# Automatically remove dependencies from package.json when using npm uninstall

Tags: node.js, npm

After `npm init` I can add dependencies in my package.json using this:

```
npm install package --save
```

And say, I want to `uninstall` the package and I do so by doing:

```
npm uninstall package
```

but I want my package.json to be updated accordingly too without me having to manually go to the file and delete that line.

From the npm docs it says:

> It is strictly additive, so it does not delete options from your package.json without a really good reason to do so.

So, I just wanted to know if this is even possible.

Comment: Since my dependencies get automatically added on package.json whenever I install with (--save) flag, I was wondering if there is a way to remove dependencies from package.json whenever I uninstall the package as well.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Use the same `--save` flag. If you installed a dependency with:

```
$> npm install grunt-cli --save
```

you can uninstall it, with package.json getting updated, using:

```
$> npm uninstall grunt-cli --save
```

The 'save' flag tells npm to update package.json based on the operation you just made it do.

Comment: I'm using npm with ember-cli and I had to use `--save-dev` instead of `--save`.

Comment: if you installed it with --save-dev, then uninstall is also --save-dev, since --save saves into the `dependencies` section of the package.json file, whereas --save-dev will save into the `devDependencies` section

Comment: I've come far since posting this question and here's a little pro-tip. 
You can use `npm i <package_name> -S` to add to your `dependencies` list or `npm i <package_name> -D` to add to your `dev-dependencies`. Same flag applies for removal with `npm rm <package_name> -S` or `npm rm <package_name> -D`

Comment: but note that these are simply the shorthand flag equivalents for --save and --save-dev. See `npm help` for all flags and their shorthand equivalents. (anything installed with -S or --save and be uninstalled using either, too, npm does not see them as different. Just "less typing" for -S)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans makes an important observation: you need to use the right flag (the one you installed with). Easy to mix this up!

Comment: You are a saint amongst men.

Answer (score 1):

In my case --save did not clear the entry from package.json, the command as suggested by **ionic-check** I think if the uninstall happens to exit with any errors package.json will not be updated in which case you only have an option to manually change package.json, this is tedious but the only way I guess

**UPDATE**

when you uninstall a package which has a dependency on other package which is active then which case uninstall may fail with errors/warnings, the safe method is through following dependency graph not sure if there any tool available, a handy tool under such operations, warning messages are quite misleading though "you must install peer dependencies.." doesn't make any sense when we are uninstalling a package

Comment: This should not be necessary: if it's in the `dependencies` list than `uninstall --save` _should_ remove it, regardless of whether something else depends on it. NPM uses rather clever dependency flattening so if you have X in your dependency list (explicitly) and you uninstall X --save, it will get removed. However, remember that there are multiple dependency lists, and `--save` is not the same as `--save-dev`, `--save-prod`,or `--save-optional`. Also yes: if your `uninstall` leads to errors, NPM stops at that error. It does not try to continue because it can't guarantee correctness anymore.