# Deleting project folder

Tags: npm, bower

Let's say i want to delete project folders with a bunch of localy installed npm packages such as gulp, gulp-sass or/and other package managers maybe bower with it's own packages.
Is it an easier way to just manualy shift+del whole folder and, well, I don't know, don't leave behind some conflicts or something?
Or maybe npm has a command to proper uninstall all packages, "uninit" folder, etc?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415523/automatically-remove-dependencies-from-package-json-when-using-npm-uninstall

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem.
At first, I copied all of packages from packages.json and run command like:

```
npm uninstall @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser @vue/cli-plugin-babel @vue/cli-plugin-eslint (... etc.) --save
```

Then, I tried to delete folder by hands, but it is deny permitions.
I open my project from **VSCode** and delete **node_modules** from tree by hands:
[Delete **node_modules** from tree by hands from **VSCode**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7EEg.png)
It was delete successfully!
p.s.: The remaining files are deleted without problems manually...